# calling reloadItemsAtIndexPaths not using dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

When I create a collection view with a custom cell (the collection view has 10 elements) by using `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier` and then call `reloadItemsAtIndexPaths` to upload cell on button click, I get **null** for properties which were set to `CustomCollectionViewCell` inside the  `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method.

I tried debugging and I found that the `initWithFrame` method of the custom cell is called the first time the app is run, and then a second time when the button is clicked for the first time.

Each time I press the button (after the first button press), the method `initWithFrame` of the custom cell is not called.

Can someone help me?
I want those properties to be stored, and not reset the first time the button is pressed.

Comment: Can you give us some code?

Comment: Fixed some grammar and some formatting